# cell colour overlaps cell borders

Tags: tables, color

This is a question that seems to be asked quite often so I apologise for the repetition. I looked in the answers already given and tried out several of them, but none seems to be the solution to my problem. As you see the colour of the cells makes random cell borders disappear, but not all of them. And if you zoom in, some more borders appear, but then again not all of them. I am very new to LaTeX and don't know a lot about it, so I would really appreciate some help.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\def\widesplit#1{%
\cleardoublepage
\def\row##1##2{##1}%
#1%
\clearpage
\def\row##1##2{##2}%
#1%
\clearpage
}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\widesplit{
\begin{tabular}{|>{\bfseries}l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
Gene
\row{ & \cellcolor{red!50} \textbf{10015-1-A1} & \cellcolor{red!50}
\textbf{10015-4-A1}  & \cellcolor{red!50} \textbf{10015-5-A1} & \cellcolor{cyan!50} \textbf{10015-6-K} & \cellcolor{cyan!50} \textbf{10015-7-K} }{& \cellcolor{cyan!50}\textbf{10015-8-K}& \cellcolor{cyan!50} \textbf{10015-9-K}& \cellcolor{red!50} \textbf{10015-10-A1} & \cellcolor{cyan!50} \textbf{10015-11-K} & \textbf{Score}}\\ \hline
CRCP
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom & 8/9}\\ \hline
GGN
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom & 9/9}\\ \hline
LRP3
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom & 9/9}\\ \hline
GAD2
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom & 8/9}\\ \hline
PRKCG
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom & 7/9}\\ \hline
IFT122
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het & 7/9}\\ \hline
SLC7A6OS
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het & 7/9}\\ \hline
KNTC1
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom & 8/9}\\ \hline
TMPRSS11F
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het & 7/9}\\ \hline
NAALAD2
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom & 8/9}\\ \hline
PION
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom & 8/9}\\ \hline
DDX18
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het & 6/9}\\ \hline
TMEM87B
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het & 6/9}\\ \hline
PRR14L
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het & 7/9}\\ \hline
RPAP3
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het & 6/9}\\ \hline
FRMD4A
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het & 7/9}\\ \hline
CARD6
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom & 7/9}\\ \hline
SLC38A4
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het & 6/9}\\ \hline
TIGIT
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het & 7/9}\\ \hline
CSMD2
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het}{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom & 6/9}\\ \hline
BMP8B
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom & 6/9}\\ \hline
ZNF643
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom & 7/9}\\ \hline
HIVEP3
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom & 7/9}\\ \hline
SZT2
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom & 7/9} \\ \hline
DYSF
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom & 7/9} \\ \hline
DIRC1
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het & 7/9}\\ \hline
FGD5
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom & 8/9} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Also and since I am already asking for help, the traditional \caption does not work here. I don't really mind it only appearing at the end of the table, but it won't happen. 
Thanx a lot in advanced.

Comment: What happens when you zoom into the cells that seem to have overlapping colours? Do the borders appear?

Answer (score 3):

there isn't a problem with the rules really if you print or zoom in they are all there, some pdf viewers are better than others at showing them.

[image]

If it bothers you that they come and go in a viewer one option is not to use them
they don't really add a lot to the understanding of the table really.

the only problem is the table is too wide

```
 Overfull \hbox (57.0684pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 81--81
```

All the width is from the heading, I don't know can you split 10015-A-A1 over two lines or show it in a smaller font or something.

In fact with a more compressed format you could probably get *both* halves of the table on to the same page as it just seems to be a binary list het/hom ?

for a caption you either need to wrap each tabular in a `table` environment so you can use

`\caption{.,....}`

Or use the `capt-of` package which lets you use captions outside `table` and figure` with the syntax

```
\captionof{table}{my caption goes here}
```

Comment: First of all, thanx man! And it was quick, too.

Comment: The warning 
    Overfull \hbox (57.0684pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 81--81
doesn't come up in my editor, though. But I will use a smaller font.  

About the pdf viewer, I have the standard Acrobat Reader. Should I switch to another one? And you say that when I print it out the lines should be there?

The capt-of worked.

Comment: The warning should be in the `.log` file (and tex echos it to teh terminal when it runs). If your editor isn't showing you tex's warnings it is not helping as much as it should;-) I expect the lines appear if you print (although to be honest I never print anymore, I can hardly remember what paper is:-)

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer that the rules are visible in all zoom-levels using any pdf-reader, you may typeset such tabulars using [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/cals):

```
\documentclass[DIV=11]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{cals, xcolor}


\let\nc=\nullcell                                                  % Shortcuts
\let\sc=\spancontent

\begin{document}

\begin{calstable}[c]

% Defining column relativ to each other and relativ to the margins
\colwidths{{\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/12*2\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/12\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/12\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/12\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/12\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/12\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/12\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/12\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/12\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/12\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/12\relax}
            }
% The tabular fills the text area

% Set up the tabular
\makeatletter
\def\cals@framers@width{0.4pt}   % Outside frame rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@framecs@width{0.4pt}
\def\cals@bodyrs@width{0.4pt}
\cals@setpadding{Ag}
\cals@setcellprevdepth{Al}
\def\cals@cs@width{0.4pt}             % Inside rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@rs@width{0.4pt}
\def\cals@bgcolor{}

\def\dred{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty
\def\cals@bgcolor{red!50}
\else \def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}

\def\dcyan{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty
\def\cals@bgcolor{cyan!50}
\else \def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}

\def\red{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty
\def\cals@bgcolor{red!15}
\else \def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}

\def\cyan{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty
\def\cals@bgcolor{cyan!15}
\else \def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}


% R1H1
\thead{\small\bfseries
\brow
    \cell{Gene}
    \dred\cell{10015-1-A1}
    \cell{10015-4-A1}
    \cell{10015-5-A1}\dred
    \dcyan\cell{10015-6-K}
    \cell{10015-7-K}
    \cell{10015-8-K}
    \cell{10015-9-K}\dcyan
    \dred\cell{10015-10-A1}\dred
    \dcyan\cell{10015-11-K}\dcyan
    \cell{Score}
\erow
\mdseries
}
% R2B1
\brow
    \cell{\bfseries CRCP}
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cell{8/9}
\erow
% R3B2
\brow
    \cell{\bfseries GGN}
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cell{9/9}
\erow
% R4B3
\brow
    \cell{\bfseries LRP3}
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cell{9/9}
\erow
% R5B4
\brow
    \cell{\bfseries GAD2}
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cell{8/9}
\erow
% R6B5
\brow
    \cell{\bfseries PRKCG}
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cell{7/9}
\erow
% R7B6
\brow
    \cell{\bfseries IFT122}
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cell{7/9}
\erow
% R8B7
\brow
    \cell{\bfseries SLC7A6OS}
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cell{7/9}
\erow
% R9B8
\brow
    \cell{\bfseries KNTC1}
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cell{8/9}
\erow
% R10B9
\brow
    \cell{\bfseries TMPRSS11F}
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cell{7/9}
\erow
% R10B9
\brow
    \cell{\bfseries NAALAD2}
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cell{8/9}
\erow
% R11B10
\brow
    \cell{\bfseries PION}
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cell{8/9}
\erow
% R12B11
\brow
    \cell{\bfseries DDX18}
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cell{6/9}
\erow
% R13B12
\brow
    \cell{\bfseries TMEM87B}
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cell{6/9}
\erow
% R14B13
\brow
    \cell{\bfseries PRR14L}
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cell{7/9}
\erow
% R15B14
\brow
    \cell{\bfseries RPAP3}
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cell{6/9}
\erow
% R16B15
\brow
    \cell{\bfseries FRMD4A}
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cell{7/9}
\erow
% R17B16
\brow
    \cell{\bfseries CARD6}
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cell{7/9}
\erow
% R18B17
\brow
    \cell{\bfseries SLC38A4}
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cell{6/9}
\erow
% R19B18
\brow
    \cell{\bfseries TIGIT}
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cell{7/9}
\erow
% R20B19
\brow
    \cell{\bfseries CSMD2}
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cell{6/9}
\erow
% R21B20
\brow
    \cell{\bfseries BMP8B}
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cell{6/9}
\erow
% R22B21
\brow
    \cell{\bfseries ZNF643}
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cell{7/9}
\erow
% R23B22
\brow
    \cell{\bfseries HIVEP3}
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cell{7/9}
\erow
% R24B23
\brow
    \cell{\bfseries SZT2}
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cell{7/9}
\erow
% R25B24
\brow
    \cell{\bfseries DYSF}
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cell{7/9}
\erow
% R26B25
\brow
    \cell{\bfseries DIRC1}
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cell{7/9}
\erow
% R27B26
\brow
    \cell{\bfseries FGD5}
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \red\cell{het}\red
    \cyan\cell{hom}\cyan
    \cell{8/9}
\erow
\makeatletter
\end{calstable}\par % \par to align the tabular

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting package `cals` :-). Is it possible with it use syntax: `\colwidths{{\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/12*2\relax}
            *{10}{{\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/12\relax}}
            }`? (+1)

Comment: @Zarko I have not tried, and the documentation does not metion this, so I assume no. The reason I use this syntax is that I then can "steal" one or two `pt` from one column and add i to another to avoid overfull boxes. That type of fine tuning is not recognisable in tabular.

Answer (score 0):

The package `nicematrix` has tools designed to address that kind of problem.

In your code, I have replaced `{tabular}` by `{NiceTabular}` with the key `color-inside` (that key specifies that there will be color instructions in the tabular).

Of course, I have loaded `nicematrix` (and unloaded several unused packages).

In the resulting PDF, the rules won't seem to vanish, whatever PDF viewer you used, at all the levels of zoom.

However, you need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\def\widesplit#1{%
\cleardoublepage
\def\row##1##2{##1}%
#1%
\clearpage
\def\row##1##2{##2}%
#1%
\clearpage
}
% \usepackage{multirow}
% \usepackage{hhline}
% \usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\widesplit{
\begin{NiceTabular}{|>{\bfseries}l|l|l|l|l|l|}[color-inside]
\hline
Gene
\row{ & \cellcolor{red!50} \textbf{10015-1-A1} & \cellcolor{red!50}
\textbf{10015-4-A1}  & \cellcolor{red!50} \textbf{10015-5-A1} & \cellcolor{cyan!50} \textbf{10015-6-K} & \cellcolor{cyan!50} \textbf{10015-7-K} }{& \cellcolor{cyan!50}\textbf{10015-8-K}& \cellcolor{cyan!50} \textbf{10015-9-K}& \cellcolor{red!50} \textbf{10015-10-A1} & \cellcolor{cyan!50} \textbf{10015-11-K} & \textbf{Score}}\\ \hline
CRCP
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom & 8/9}\\ \hline
GGN
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom & 9/9}\\ \hline
LRP3
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom & 9/9}\\ \hline
GAD2
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom & 8/9}\\ \hline
PRKCG
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom & 7/9}\\ \hline
IFT122
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het & 7/9}\\ \hline
SLC7A6OS
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het & 7/9}\\ \hline
KNTC1
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom & 8/9}\\ \hline
TMPRSS11F
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het & 7/9}\\ \hline
NAALAD2
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom & 8/9}\\ \hline
PION
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom & 8/9}\\ \hline
DDX18
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het & 6/9}\\ \hline
TMEM87B
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het & 6/9}\\ \hline
PRR14L
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het & 7/9}\\ \hline
RPAP3
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het & 6/9}\\ \hline
FRMD4A
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het & 7/9}\\ \hline
CARD6
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom & 7/9}\\ \hline
SLC38A4
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het & 6/9}\\ \hline
TIGIT
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het & 7/9}\\ \hline
CSMD2
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het}{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom & 6/9}\\ \hline
BMP8B
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom & 6/9}\\ \hline
ZNF643
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom & 7/9}\\ \hline
HIVEP3
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom & 7/9}\\ \hline
SZT2
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom & 7/9} \\ \hline
DYSF
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom & 7/9} \\ \hline
DIRC1
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het & 7/9}\\ \hline
FGD5
\row{&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom}{&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom&\cellcolor{red!15}het&\cellcolor{cyan!15}hom & 8/9} \\ \hline
\end{NiceTabular}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]